# CSS: Extend div to fit the whole page

Tags: css

I am trying to find a way to extend a `div` to fit the rest of the page, without using `JavaScript`.

Some code I written to start with:

**HTML:**

```
​<div class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bodyContainer {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 50px; 
 height: 100%;    
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The code above doesn't extend the `div` to fit the rest of the page.

​I also started a `JSFiddle` to see what happens. Link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewtomici/BwVWx/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the height and width to the html and body elements also:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/BwVWx/4/

Comment: I guess this is the right way :) Thanks for the missing code.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above have correct information but I am adding some gaps in information for those that are new to CSS.

If you just add a class and try to make your div 100%, you will get this

[image]

So you have to add `100%` to the height of the `body` and `html`

[image]

You will still have "white space" around the div. So remove padding and margins.

[image]

### CSS

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* your class for the div should have 100% height and width */
.bg-full {
  background-color: #777; /* you can add a color to visually test your code */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can view a demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/ZQzrJg)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `height: 100%;` for the HTML and BODY element:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BwVWx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` css property to avoid horizontal scroll bar display.
Here is your [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/BwVWx/2/).

About [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) css property.